# Camera crashing on Android 10 when launching intent

Tags: android

I'm trying to add the ability to take a photo to my app which should be fairly simple however I'm running into issues on android 10 for some reason.

I followed the implementation details at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics (so far I've only implemented the basic functionality which should launch the camera app and return a bitmap of the thumbnail)

This all works on older emulated devices however when I test it on my physical Google Pixel and an emulated Pixel 2 (both running Android 10) I get a crash after calling startActivity:

```
btnCam.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
});
```

The problem is, its not my app thats crashing but the camera app. If I look in logcat after the crash I get the following message:

```
2020-02-02 17:11:29.059 15592-15592/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera, PID: 15592
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.google.android.apps.camera.legacy.app.activity.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.google.android.apps.camera.legacy.app.activity.CaptureActivity.onCreate(PG:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Logically given its crashing with `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array` I imagine its expecting some form of input that I'm not providing however I haven't found any mention of having to provide any extra parameters (I'm aware you can specify optional params to specify where to write the resulting photo to but nothing has said this is required)

Is anyone aware of this issue and how to resolve it on Android 10?

Thanks

Comment: Try different Camera apps. There are plenty in the store.

Comment: That's not really an option, I cant force all users of my app to install a third party application just to use the camera

Comment: You only will do that for your self of course. Just test so you will know. And users can prefer a different camera app and then your app should work too.

Comment: Yeah but the vast majority of users will have the default camera app so that's what I need to support, not a random third party app (it doesn't really matter if a third party app works)

Comment: Did you find solution for your problem. I'm having a null pointer problem but it is working fine when I'm using android 9 and below 9 not for android 10 and 11 why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you have to check the camera permission , also add camera permission in the manifest file. check the code as below

1. Add   in AndroidManifest.xml file
2. check camera Permission.

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 100;  
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
      newString[]{
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
      },
      MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }else{
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
```

3. ```
       public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
           super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

           switch (requestCode) {

               case MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE: {
                   if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       showPictureDialog();
                   } else {
                       Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                               .make(relativeLayout, "Please Allow Permission", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                               .setAction("Setting", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       Intent intent = new Intent();
                                       intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                       Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                       intent.setData(uri);
                                       startActivity(intent);
                                   }
                               });
                       snackbar.show();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```

4.

```
     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

5. save the image to the storage

```
    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Well now I'm just annoyed, I could have sworn I'd updated the manifest file and given it was working on the older emulators I didn't even think of checking but that was it, I was missing the stupid camera permission. Anyway thank you for your detailed answer, I'd also forgotten that requesting runtime permissions was a thing so thanks for that example.

Comment: Although this answer indeed has useful info about how to request permissions, the solution provided is wrong as it is not need camera permission for calling camera app through intent. The accepted answer should be the @tronman one right below!

Answer (score 2):

According to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296554/camera-intent-permissions-in-android-10), this is a bug in the camera app which has recently been corrected. There is no need for your app to request permission to use the camera when you are using the camera app to take the photo.

But if you need your app to work on an API 29 emulator or device before the bug fix is pushed out, you can just add a `<uses-permission>` for any type of permission (even a fake one) to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...>
   <uses-permission android:name="BLAH" />
   ...

</manifest>
```

Comment: Man!!... You are my hero!!!... I've lost lots of time trying to find a solution to this awkward problem!!